Duplicate resource error when adding images with the same name for different flavors
I'm working on an application which has different build flavors, each flavor has different images. When I try to add the drawables, I get duplicate resources error:


Execution failed for task ':app:mergeStagingReleaseResources'. Caused by: [mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_fastsim_logo]
/Users/name/StudioProjects/project_name/app/src/staging/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_name_logo.webp [mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_name_logo]
/Users/name/StudioProjects/projectName/app/src/Staging/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_name_logo.webp: Error: Duplicate resources

and so on with the other images.....

this is an image for the structure of the different folders

